# Why is a filter throwing a not callable error on the parent

Tags: python, callable

I have a python class named `MyFilter`. In one of the methods I filter a list:

```
def __gatherCommits(self, head, count=2, commits=[]):
    next_commits = self.repo.iter_commits(head, max_count=count)
    filtered_commits = list(filter(lambda x: x.committed_date == self.current_day, next_commits))
```

That last line is causing an error to be thrown:

```
File "MyFilter.py", line 22, in __gatherCommits
    filtered_commits = list(filter(lambda x: x.committed_date == self.current_day, next_commits))
TypeError: 'MyFilter' object is not callable
```

When I remove the offending line it runs as expected.

Comment: Did you accidentally name an instance `list` or `filter`?

Comment: Mark may have it, but my guess is you named something else "filter".

Comment: Psychic debugging: You've created, at global scope, an object named `filter` (or maybe `list`, but `filter` would fit better) that is an instance of a class `MyFilter`. Thus, you've denied yourself access to the built-in `filter` function. Don't name shadow built-ins.

Answer (score 0):

That was it exactly. Thanks folks. I was testing the class by instantiating an instance of the class with the variable `filter`. :face-palm: